# Create dynamic collection in MongoDB using Sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am working with SailsJs+MongoDB API. I have  to create New  colletion in mongoDB .Name of colletion will be in request Parameter.

example:

Suppose I want to create 'Users'  collection in  'mongoDbDatabase' database
   by following request.

```
 {
    "collectionName" : "Users",
    "dbName"    :"mongoDbDatabase"
    }
```

Now is there any way to create dynamic collection in mongoDB using `req.param('collectionName)` variable ?

Answer (score 1):

To use all the tools that Sails provides, you have to add code (before you start your app) for each Model / Collection you are planning to interact with. As a result, creating a collection dynamically will mean you can't take advantage of the whole data - framework sails provides.

Are you sure you need a dynamic collection? Why not a defined collection differentiated by attributes?

If you really need to do this from Sails, [it looks like you can get access to the underlying raw mongo database](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/manager):

```
var db = AnyModel.getDatastore().manager; // the database will be as defined in config/models.js or config/connections.js

var collectionName = 'Widgets';
db.createCollection(collectionName);

// note, even if this works, something like 'Widgets.find' will not.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , and you are right . That  I will not able to use queries of collection provided by sails for dynamic created tables.
as per your suggestions , I'll try to make changes in DB Design and will try to work out with  attribute differentiation. Thanks